# Compress to a single file .nii.gz wont work

Tags: 16.04, zip, gzip

I have several files with `.nii` format, I wanted to create a single file with `.nii.gz` format, so I opened the terminal and `cd` to where I keep my `.nii` files and then used this command:

```
gzip *.nii
```

but the output is not a single `.nii.gz` file, now every file is archived in a `.nii.gz` file.

Comment: Do you *really* want to create a single (concatenated) file, or a compressed archive from which you can later extract the original files?

Comment: @steeldriver The later (compressed archive from which you can later extract the original files)

Answer (score 3):

`gzip` is a compression format that is only capable of compressing one single file. It can not handle multiple files or directory structures.

That's why it's often used together with `tar`, the "**t**ape **ar**chive" tool, which can compile multiple files or directories together into one archive file.

However, you can do both steps of collecting the files together into a so-called "tar-ball" and to compress that archive with the `gzip` algorithm at once, because `tar` has a compression option:

```
tar -czf archive.tar.gz *.nii
```

So what does this `tar` command do?

- `-c` is its command to **c**reate a new archive
- `-z` tells it to use the `gzip` algorithm to compress the generated archive
- `-f archive.tar.gz` specifies to use "archive.tar.gz" as output file. The file name extension `.tar.gz` is not mandatory but recommended.

`*.nii` specifies the input file(s) and/or folder(s) you want to archive.